# Symfony2 render many times template

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-2.7

I created action in my controller

```
    /**
     * @Route("admin/choice-lists/{choiceListGroup}", name="admin_choice_lists_show")
     */
    public function show($choiceListGroup = 'PaymentMethod')
    {

        $choiceListRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:ChoiceList');
        $choiceLists = $choiceListRepository->findAllByGroup('PaymentMethod');


        return $this->render('choice_list/show.html.twig');

    }
```

As you can see, there is optional parameters choiceListGroup, next I created view

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Choice List</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endblock%}
```

Now when I run my app from web, Symfony2 renders my view many times.
It looks as if Symfony2 call rendering in loop.
When I delete optional parameter from routing or delete 'extends' from view everythings is ok. Also when I return Json Response instead of $this->render I get result one time.

Comment: Firstly, create a valid Action in your controller: `public function showAction() { ... }`

Comment: Did you edit your posted code for 'clarity'?  I don't see how your template is doing much of anything except putting out an empty table.  And I don't see the controller passing any data in the render call.

Comment: Would be nice to see the actual error - the html output where the view is rendered many times.

Comment: It may come from your base.html.twig file.

Comment: As @scoolnico says, it doesn't seem to be a real action, so it's harder to follow. Also, the `showAction($choiceListGroup = 'PaymentMethod')` parameter is not used in the action. And the template really is showing nothing... Is that the real code?